# Is there someway in Informatica where I can change the post session failure commands for multiple sessions in a single script?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I am trying to add post session failure command as a reusable task. I have to add it for more than 1000 sessions which are quite tedious. I am looking for the possibility if I can do it using some script or any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your only option is to export your workflows, edit the xml (e.g. find and replace) and import them back.